# Microsoft DirectX SDK installation fails with error code S1018

Tags: c++, sdk, directx

I'm trying to install Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010) downloaded from microsoft.com and I keep getting error S1018 all the time. Does anyone know what it might be?
I'm using Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error not long ago. The issue is something is using 1 of the DirectX run time files that it is trying to install, probably into the Windows folder.

Quit as many programs as possible, including Visual Studio, Steam, any media players, any graphics software, ...

If this still fails, try installing from safe mode.

Despite looking like a critical error, all of the development files are present, and most of the system files should also be there, so even if you cant get it to install successfully it should still work